# Button with multiple text

Tags: android, user-interface

I have created a small calculator app. 
Currently, it is showing buttons like this : 
[image]

I want to show it something like this :

[image]

2 things :

1) How to make sin^-1 of different color + superscript , so that user knows that long press will cause him to use inverse.
2) Writing -1 in superscript.

Comment: So, -1 should be a super-super-script?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using HTML.

**sin button** -

```
sinbutton.setText(Html.fromHtml("sin<span style="color:blue"><sup>sin<sup>-1</sup></sup></span>"));
```

---

Similarly for other buttons -

**cos** -

```
cosbuttton.setText(Html.fromHtml("cos<span style="color:blue"><sup>cos<sup>-1</sup></sup></span>"));
```

**tan** -

```
tanbutton.setText(Html.fromHtml("tan<span style="color:blue"><sup>tan<sup>-1</sup></sup></span>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this: you can set and format your text as per your requirement.

```
btn.setText(Html.fromHtml("sin<font color='red'><sup>-1</sup></font>"));
```

Answer (score -1):

In string

```
<string name="sin">sin</string>
<string name="_1">-1</string>
```

In onCreate()

```
sinButton.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.sin)+"<sup><font color='#FF0000'>"+getResources().getString(R.string.sin)+"<sup>"+getResources().getString(R.string._1)+"</sup>"+"</font></sup>"));
```

Comment: Hey! Down voter! Can you please tell me why you down voted my answer?